# Join same table without duplicate in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have one table to join multiple times based on condition.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WLpp7.png)

I have attach table screenshot, there are more than 10k+ records in table.

Query I am using right now

```
SELECT 
    table.invoice_id,  
    a1.product_price AS attr_val1,
    a2.product_price AS attr_val2,
    a3.product_price AS attr_val3,
    a4.total_price AS attr_val4
FROM table
    LEFT JOIN table a1 ON table.invoice_id=a1.invoice_id AND a1.product_id='7078'
    LEFT JOIN table a2 ON table.invoice_id=a2.invoice_id AND a2.product_id='7071'
    LEFT JOIN table a3 ON table.invoice_id=a3.invoice_id AND a3.product_id='7085'
    LEFT JOIN table a4 ON table.invoice_id=a4.invoice_id AND a4.total_price='0'
```

I am getting duplicate row

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5djhr.png)

expecting result below

```
FAC-35072  |  59.98  | 209.94 | 14.90 | 341.80
```

Comment: please show your actual query?  you've changed some things in what you show and introduced errors

Comment: you will also likely need to show sample data and actual and expected results for that sample data

Comment: updated question as per query

Comment: [Tips for asking a good Structured Query Language (SQL) question](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055), "5. Some Additional Suggestions".

Comment: You are selecting `FROM lissac_ventes`, and how many rows are in that table where`Invoice_ID="FAC-35072"` ?  (HINT: How many times is the result repeated?)

Comment: @Luuk you should make that an answer

Comment: There are a lot of invoice id.

Answer (score 0):

Because you are selecting from a table (in your case from `table`) yhe result will be every record that is in table.

So, when you have 5 records with `Invoice_ID="FAC-35072"`, you end up with 5 records.

One way to solve the duplicate records is using [DISTINCT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/select.html#:%7E:text=%5BALL%20%7C-,DISTINCT,-%7C%20DISTINCTROW%20%5D)